# How to bridge ethernet interface running dhcp server

Tags: qemu, isc-dhcpd

A workstation has `eth0` interface running as a dhcp server with the following settings

```
auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  network 10.0.0.0
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  gateway 10.0.0.1
  broadcast 0.255.255.255
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

  
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 {
    range 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.254;
    option time-servers 10.0.0.1;
    option broadcast-address 10.255.255.255;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

Is it possible to create a bridge with `eth0` without changing any DHCP configuration settings so that any machine created in QEMU gets assigned an IP address on the defined NIC given by the DHCP server

the workstation is connected to a switch and other machines are connected to the switch as well, the goal is to be able to access the vms from other machines on the network by using the ip address `10.0.0.X`

Comment: Please give somewhat better description. Where the DHCP server is running? Where do you plan to run your VM? Your description looks like that DHCP-server runs on workstation, and your VM will be hosted on the same workstation? What kind of VM?

Comment: @A.B no the switch is not configurable

Comment: @schweik both the DHCP and the QEMU software running the vms are located on the workstation, i would like to keep the DHCP running on `eth0` while being able to connect to any vm running on the workstation using an IP address similar to this one `10.0.0.X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to define the initial interface as a bridge.  e.g. delete your `iface eth0 ...` definition in `/etc/network/interfaces`, replace it with a definition for `iface br0`.

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1/8
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_maxwait 0
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_hello 2
  bridge_maxage 12
```

Once that is done, you will have to configure the VM to use bridged network `br0`.

You will no longer have your IP address(es) on `eth0`.  It/they will be on `br0` instead.  This is relatively unimportant, and rarely makes any difference to anything - only for programs that care about interface names.  Most don't, but some do...e.g. some daemons (such as `dhcpd` or `arpwatch`), or when running `tcpdump` you'd need to use `tcpdump -i br0` instead of `tcpdump -i eth0`.  `dhclient` too, of course, but you shouldn't be running a dhcp client on the same interface & machine that you're running a dhcp server.  Anyway, these will all need to be reconfigured to use `br0`.

If your dhcp server is the same machine as your workstation, you will also need to configure `dhcpd` to use `br0` rather than `eth0`.

You seem to be running Debian (or a derivative of Debian), so you can probably configure that in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.  e.g. I have the following in mine, to listen on both br0 (for VMs and for physical hosts on my LAN) and my wireless interface wlan0 (for phones, laptops, tablets, etc):

```
INTERFACESv4="br0 wlan0"
```

You'll need to either reboot or restart the networking for  eth0/br0 with something like `ifdown eth0 ; sleep 5; ifup br0`.  If you're doing this over `ssh` or similar, it's important to run this as ONE command line, otherwise you won't be able to bring up br0 when eth0 goes down.  The `sleep 5` is there because I've found it's good to wait a few seconds between downing an iface and bringing it back up again.

Some network daemons will need to be restarted after eth0 goes away - if you have lots of daemons listening on eth0 it's probably easier to just reboot than restart them all.

Comment: what if i don't want to change the `eth0` configuration and would prefer to leave the ip address 10.0.0.1 to that interface

Comment: then you'll have to figure out another way.  can't see why you'd want to, though - apart from the interface name, everything works exactly the same.  br0 uses eth0 as its underlying hardware.

Comment: this does the job but I don't fully understand how this works can you update your answer into a more detailed one and maybe include a diagram of how everything is connected, the thing that confuses me is that `eth0` does not have an ip assigned but some how i am able to ssh into the work station through it

Comment: The IP address is on br0 (which is a bridge interface between eth0 and...ummm...nothing.  Normally a bridge "bridges" two or more separate network segments.  Here it can be thought of as bridging real network eth0 and whatever virtual network interface is used by your VMs).  It works exactly the same as if it was on eth0.   To other machines on the LAN, it's indistinguishable.  sshd doesn't care at all whether the IP address is on an interface named eth0 or br0, it only cares about the IP address.

Comment: BTW, one thing that may be confusing you is that I replaced `network`, `netmask`, `address`, `broadcast`, and `gateway` entries with just `address 10.0.0.1/8`.   `ifup` figures out all the rest from that CIDR address/mask.  BTW, a `gateway` entry pointing to itself doesn't make much sense, anyway....it's not much use as a default route (and is probably over-ridden by your ppp/dsl/wireless/whatever internet link anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As you specified the VM is KVM/qemu you have better to start with the qemu-networking. There are 3 variants: 1) user, 2) tap, 3) passthrough.

1. `-netdev user,` - means that the VM guest is completely isolated inside a private IP range subnet 10.0.2.0/24 by default, and the integrated qemu-DHCP-server gives your VM interface the IP: 10.0.2.15 address. This subnet is connecting to host interface through NAT firewall, and you can enable/disable the firewall at the startup. Even if enabled, you cannot simply connect the VM from outside unless you enable port forwarding with a parameter:

`-netdev user,id=n0,hostfwd=hostip:hostport-guestip:guestport`

2. `-netdev tap,` gives you a chance to connect your VM eth0 interface through a [tap] - [br0 bridge] - [eth0 host interface]. Here you have take into account, that at the host level you have to configure the br0 interface not the host eth0. There is no default IP given to the VM, hence you must configure it in a usual way. This is useful if you want too connect more VM running on the same host, and there is no restriction to see all ports from the VM each other and from outside of the box.
3. passthrough is the ultimate variant which is based on a possibility to pass full control of a PCI network card to VM. This is not simple configuration and you can find it in some tutorial examples. This completely takes the card out from host kernel control and if you need an network connection for host, your host must have at least two NIC.

My advice: Thing over the goal of using your VM networking. If you need to use the VM for client only or you plan to have just a single open port of some server service the -netdev user is the most simple way, while host-DHCP server is obsolete. If you plan more complicated use of your VM or interconnect more VMs running on the same host, the TAP is the right choice. For completely isolated VM use the NIC  passthrough.

P.S. Yes, I did not notice a `-netdev socket,` but it is not for interfacing VM out of the box, but for interconnect more VMs inside a single host.